# Rss Reader Android not working

Tags: android, rss

I want to make a simple Rss Reader app and it doesn't working. More exactly, it doesn't show nothing, almost nothing. For example, for this feed http://feeds.feedburner.com/telefoane-mobilissimo, I get "https://www.mobilissimo.ro/telefoane/" and "Telefoane mobile: specificații, galerii foto, video, benchmark-uri, teste".
Here is the code:

```
public List<FeedModel> parseFeed(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {
        String title = null;
        String description = null;
        String link=null;
        String content=null;
        String pubDate=null;
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL url;
        boolean isItem = false;
        List<FeedModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = Xml.newPullParser();
            xmlPullParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            xmlPullParser.setInput(inputStream, null);

            xmlPullParser.nextTag();
            while (xmlPullParser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();

                String name = xmlPullParser.getName();
                if(name == null)
                    continue;

                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        isItem = false;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        isItem = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                String result = "";
                if (xmlPullParser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    result = xmlPullParser.getText();
                    xmlPullParser.nextTag();
                }
                System.out.println(result);
                System.out.println(isItem);
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    title = result;
                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                    description = result.substring(result.indexOf("<img"));
                }
                else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
                    pubDate=result;
                else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
                    link = result;
                else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded"))
                    content=result.substring(result.indexOf("<div"),result.indexOf("]]")-1);

                if (description!=null&&description.startsWith("<img"))
                {
                    System.out.println(description.substring(10,74));
                    url=new URL(description.substring(10,74));
                    description=description.substring(description.indexOf("/>")+2);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                }


                if (title != null && description != null && bitmap!=null && link!=null) {
                    if(isItem) {
                        FeedModel item = new FeedModel(title, description, pubDate, content, bitmap, feed, link);
                        items.add(item);
                    }

                    title = null;
                    description = null;
                    pubDate=null;
                    link=null;
                    content=null;
                    bitmap=null;
                    isItem = false;
                }
            }

            return items;
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    public class FeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        private String feedTask;

        public FeedTask(String feed)
        {
            this.feedTask=feed;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (anInt==1)
            {
                MainActivity.this.anInt=0;
                centerError.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime)).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        centerError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                    }
                });
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            recyclerView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(feedTask);
                InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                feedModelList = parseFeed(inputStream);

            }
            catch (Exception e){}
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (feedModelList!=null) {
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new FeedAdapter(feedModelList, MainActivity.this));
                recyclerView.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
            }
            else System.out.println("heeey");
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
```